# SQL Server 2008: Is it possible to set the recovery model to simple for a single table in a database?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table which stores data out of a complex query. This table is truncated and new populated once per hour. As you might assume this is for performance reason so the application accesses this table and not the query.

Now the drawback is a huge transaction log. There is no need transaction logging for this table.

Comment: Have you considered sticking this table in `tempdb`? It will have simple recovery model and some additional logging optimisations too. You would need a start up stored procedure to populate it after service restart though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is it possible to set the recovery model to simple for a single table
>   in a database?*

**No.**

The recovery model is a **per database** setting - you cannot have different settings for different tables in the same database.

The recovery model can only be set at the **database level**.

Answer (score 2):

As marc says, not within the same database - but you could place it in another database on the same server and link the databases so that you can still include it within queries, but it sits on it's own database, with its own backup regime / transaction log settings.